# Is there a way to obtain a list of exception handlers classes/methods available in the context?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I'm working on a Rest API. Currently, I'm trying to handle some wrong client input. So far so good, I have it working with java validation.

There is an specific case where I may have an odd client input for dates. Here's a mvce:

```
public class Input {
    @NotNull(message = "Usage to should have a valid date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime someDateTime;
    //getters and setters
}

public class Output {
    //content not relevant for the case...
}

@RestController
public class FooController {

    @PostMapping(path="/url", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Output> foo(@Valid @ResponseBody Input input) {
        //implementation details...
    }
}
```

When testing it, this input works ok:

```
{
    "someDateTime": "2019-01-01 00:00:00"
}
```

And this doesn't (time is missing):

```
{
    "someDateTime": "2019-01-01"
}
```

For the latest input sample, I get an `HttpMessageNotReadableException` (from Spring).

I was trying to solve this by adding a method in a global exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> customSpringInputHandler(
            HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .body(new ErrorResponse(CLIENT_INPUT_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```

With this, now I get a more detailed exception message. Sadly, this message is too verbose to return to the clients of this API because it depicts some of the internal design of the application.

I can see this `HttpMessageNotReadableException` wraps an `InvalidFormatException` (from Jackson) that's better for me to use. Thing is, handling specific cases of the case of `HttpMessageNotReadableException` in a single method seems kinda fishy. I was thinking on create a specific exception handler for `InvalidFormatException` and then delegate that execution from this method. Now I want to know how Spring can provide me those handlers and do the proper delegation.

I had something built in JAX-RS in the past, it was like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected <T extends Throwable> Response callChainedMapper(T wrappedException, Exception baseException) {
    Response response;
    ExceptionMapper<T> mapper = (ExceptionMapper<T>) providers.getExceptionMapper(wrappedException.getClass());

    //no mapper could be found, so treat it as a generic exception
    if (mapper == null) {
        ExceptionMapper<Exception> generalExceptionMapper = (ExceptionMapper<Exception>) providers
                .getExceptionMapper(Exception.class);
        response = generalExceptionMapper.toResponse(baseException);
    } else {
        response = mapper.toResponse(wrappedException);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Can I do something similar in Spring? Or maybe is there another alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Not aware Spring provides specific feature for such delegation. But you can simply 
do it by yourself by the following pattern. The `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` provided by Spring also use this kind of pattern.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler({
        HttpMessageNotReadableException.class ,
        InvalidFormatException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> customSpringInputHandler(Exception ex) {
        if(ex instanceof HttpMessageNotReadableException){
            return handle((HttpMessageNotReadableException) ex);
        }else if(ex instance of InvalidFormatException) {
            return handle((InvalidFormatException) ex);
        }else{
           throw ex;
        }
    }

    private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex){
        //get the wrapped InvalidFormatException and call handle(invalidFormatException)
    }

    private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(InvalidFormatException ex){

    }

}
```